# Powering AC Appliance with DC

Tags: battery-operated, speakers, appliances, dc-ac

I have an AC speaker set and it is plugged into an outlet. Then the outlet is put into a transformer where the transformer output is 17V 2.5A AC. Then from the transformer is put through a bridge rectifier and turned DC. My question is, how powerful of a battery will I need to power it?

(I'm assuming that I simply need to connect the battery leads to the output of the bridge rectifier.)

Update: 
Just figured out that the amp chip is a TDA8947J, if that helps at all :)

Comment: What's after the bridge rectifier inside it?

Comment: @winny The amp chip

Comment: Should be no problem. Just be careful that a 24 V fully charged battery can be 29 V when fully charged. Check the specs on the amp chip if possible.

Comment: [TDA8947J](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/TDA8947J.pdf) has a maximum supply voltage of 28V.

Comment: @user2943160 if I used a 24v voltage regulator, could that perhaps prevent the battery from exceeding 24 volts?

Comment: The regulator would go between the battery and the internal connections to the diode bridge outputs.

Answer (score 5):

If it's just an audio amplifier it should work without damage at reduced voltage. You can try it at 12 to 14 V from your car battery, for example.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPaIBW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. AC/DC power can be used for AC/DC music.*

- Adding D5 will prevent backfeed into your battery when mains is on.
- If battery DC voltage is less than mains DC voltage the diodes will ensure that the unit always runs on mains when available.
- Use your multimeter to measure the actual DC voltage after the bridge rectifier. That's probably your maximum battery voltage. Minimum might be half to 2/3 of that. Pick a battery voltage to suit.
- If you can break into the DC line somewhere you can measure the current. Use the 10 A range with the probes in the correct sockets.

$$ Battery~life~(hours) = \frac {Battery~Ah~rating}{Amplifier~current} $$

Size battery to suit.

Comment: Remember to play both Highway to hell, Thunderstock and Back in black!

Answer (score 1):

17VAC RMS will give you a DC voltage of roughly 17 * 1.4142 - 1.2V = 23VDC at the smoothing capacitors after the diode bridge. So a 24V battery can likely be connected at the output of the diode bridge.

Comment: If using lead acid batteries, the 2x13.7V float comes remarkably close to the TDA8947J's absolute maximum voltage of 28V. Charging at 2x14.5V would exceed that.