# How can I reuse an AC speaker amplifier board with DC?

Tags: dc, ac-dc

I'm planning to reuse this board powering it with a computer 12V DC power supply.

[image: AC powered audio amplifier board from old speakers]

It gets 9V AC 200mA from its own 220V AC transformer.

I have basic understanding of electronics, so I've been searching about AC to DC conversion.
I found https://www.instructables.com/AC-to-DC-Conversion/ and [Powering AC Appliance with DC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246487/powering-ac-appliance-with-dc), but I'm not sure how to apply it.

The specs for the [TDA2822](http://www.unisonic.com.tw/datasheet/TDA2822.pdf) stand that it operates normally on 12V and at an absolute maximum rate of 15V.

Measuring with a multimeter on the capacitor I get 13.90V DC. But I'm not sure if I have to get the measure there, or somewhere further on the circuit.

Is it right to just plug 12V from my power supply on the capacitor leads? Or I must remove it along with the four diodes?

Can somebody point me into the right path?

Thanks.

Comment: Just connect 12VDC with either polarity to "AC In" and let the bridge rectifier (D1 to D4) take care of it. Assuming your DC supply is isolated from the audio inputs...

Comment: Looks like it. You can also connect 12VDC to the AC in. The diodes will waste about 1.2V

Comment: Yes you can connect to Cap directly and diodes will block any current going to an open input.

Comment: Looks to me as though connecting DC to the capacitor will bypass the on/off switch. Not a problem if you're prepared to switch it on or off at the supply - otherwise connect the +ve to the switch terminals before the capacitor instead.

Comment: Power supplies raise a bunch of risks from electrocution, fire, etc.  I wouldn't suggest fooling around with power supply circuitry as an initial EE project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it right to just plug 12V from my power supply on the capacitor leads? Or I must remove it along with the four diodes?

Yes, you can connect to capacitor, but the "ON/OFF" switch won't work.
For the ON/OFF switch to enable/disable the amplifier, connect your 12V DC supply as below. Powering from **both** AC source AND your 12V DC supply at the same time might cause problems. Use one OR the other.
[image: 12V DC supply with working switch]

Answer (score 2):

It does look like AC input just goes through the full bridge diodes and power switch to the largest capacitor, and the capacitor negative lead looks like to be the common negative for the whole circuit.

So based on that, you don't need to remove anything.

Answer (score 2):

You have the option of using the switch as shown below as it is wired, or going directly to the Cap.  Bridge has no effect when transformer is not used.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnHrLG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]